# Winsock send function acting up

Tags: c++, string, winsock

This seems like a very simple problem but it's being a great problem to me.  After awhile I returned to a project of mine and, the oddest thing, every time I try and add a send() function call the data is never transmitted (I discovered through putty).  The old function calls work it just doesn't work when I add new ones.  Can anyone tell me what coudl cause the first function call to work and not the second.  They are right next to each other.  I am transmitting the data to a Java applet if that helps but putty says it's a server problem.  Here's the code where connsock is the socket id number for the client.

```
 string testsendbuf = "Hello there\r\n";
 string addbuf = "Hello again\r\n";
send( connsock, testsendbuf.c_str(), testsendbuf.length(), 0);
send( connsock, addbuf.c_str(), addbuf.length(), 0 );
```

Again the first works but the second doesn't.  What could cause this?

I tested the error code and there was none and the bytes transfered was accurate

Comment: Did you check the return values of the `send` calls?

Comment: Sorry, how exactly do you check... I found it on Google but I still can't figure out how to check.  is it like resultvalue == WSAEACCES

Comment: `send` returns the number of bytes sent, or `SOCKET_ERROR`. If it is `SOCKET_ERROR` you get the actual error code with `WSAGetLastError`. The possible errors are all listed in [the manual page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740149(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Check the return value by doing `if (send([params]) == SOCKET_ERROR) { cout << "Socket error: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl; /* exit the program */ }`

Comment: it says error 0. So no error.

Comment: A return-value of zero means it sent no data and it didn't fail sending no data. Check that the length parameter is not zero.

Comment: the error code was 0 but when I checked the actual value it was 15

Comment: Could the other end be disconnecting after receiving? I'd connect to the java app with putty and see how it acts.

Comment: nope the client stays connected all the while

Answer (score 0):

If your socket is marked as `Non-Blocking` there is a good chance the other send is still in progress and you are getting a error of `WSAEWOULDBLOCK`

Change to blocking sockets or try a loop (example to show how works, production code different) :

```
int pos =0;
for(;;)
{

    pos += send(connsock,addbuf.c_str() + pos ,addbuf.size() - pos,0);

    if (pos == addbuff.size()
        break;
    int nError=WSAGetLastError();
    if(nError!=WSAEWOULDBLOCK&&nError!=0)
    {
        std::cout<<"Winsock error : "<<nError<<"\r\n";
        shutdown(connsock,SD_SEND);
        closesocket(connsock);
        break;
    }
    Sleep(1000);
}
```

Side note:  Would build a buffer with everything you want to send. Instead of back to back calls to `send()`.

Comment: When I check the error value for send() I get a 0 as an error value and  think 0 means no error.  Also when I check the return value I get the correct number of bytes

Comment: Thanks for all the useful source though

Comment: What happens when you try to send `"Hello there\r\nHello again\r\n"` at one time?;

Comment: Everything after the first \r\n is ignored

Comment: Problem is not with this code than. Is the other end, or the other end expects something different.

Comment: I thought the same but putty says the string was never sent

Comment: I'd say this breaks the Q&A format here. Try bringing problem to chat.  and see if someone can help you.